# Putting a div under text

Tags: html, css

My HTML code:

```
<div id="backgroundH"></div>

<div id="header">
    <h2> Premium Store </h2>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
#backgroundH {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

#header {
    top:-50px;
    color:black;   
    font-family:Courier New;
}

body {
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

So why isn't it working? I tried everything. Can somebody show me how to put that text over my div which I am using as a background in this case?

It should look like a gray background underneath a text which says "premium store".

Comment: is this you need? http://jsfiddle.net/C6B4K/1/ or this one http://jsfiddle.net/C6B4K/2/

Comment: If you're trying to position `<div>` blocks over each other you can use positioning and `z-index` to layer or stack them.

Comment: It’s difficult to say what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like something that would best be handled with a simple background setting and possibly a bottom border (and padding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the order of your divs wrong it should be like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mCGt8/

html:

```
<div id="backgroundH">        
    <div id="header">
        <h2> Premium Store </h2>
    </div>        
</div>
```

css:

```
#backgroundH {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dddddd;       
}

#header {    
  top:-50px;
  color:black;   
  font-family:Courier New;
}

body {
  background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In text-div you are using `top: -50px`, so I believe you want text-div sibling to background-div and you missed `position: relative`.

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    color: black;   
    font-family: Courier New;
}
```

The problem with `position: relative` is that the space that div would fill before `top: -50px` stills there.

So, you have 2 ways:

1. CSS: use `margin-top: -50px;`
2. HTML: nest text-div to background-div if it's possible. (preferred)